# What happens when you copy a mac user folder to the equivalent kubuntu user?

Tags: kubuntu, users

Mootivation: I'd love to migrate all my data on my mac to kubuntu.

What happens if I copy my mac user /Users/{username}/ to a linux user (the equivalent of /Users/{username})?

Will anything break?

Comment: Copy it how? Over NFS or Samba on the Linux machine connected to the Mac? Over NFS or Samba on the Mac machine connected to the Linux? Dual-booted the mac into Ubuntu? Made tar archive in the mac and extracted in Linux?

Comment: Copying the /Users/$USERNAME directory would copy these configuration files and would not transfer any valuable (or working) data to Kubuntu (because Mac config files or different than Kubuntu config files and are not therefore transferable), except for unnecessary data. See the answer that Vanadium posted.

Answer (score 4):

Don't.

Just copy your user data over: documents, pictures, etc. Do not copy configuration data over from a totally different operating system. Many of that configuration data will not be used so just take disk space, and, worse, there is a chance that you will cause some annoyances or problems because of incompatible configuration information.